# NSScrollView/NSCollectionView on NSVisualEffectView cause flickering

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa, nsvisualeffectview

I have a **NSCollectionView** within a **NSVisualEffectView** within a **NSPopover**. Everytime when it's refreshing(add, remove, reload **NSCollectionViewItem**, or even just click buttons on the **NSCollectionViewItem's** view), it has glitches on the *controls*.

Here's a screenshot I try to get when it's opening:

[image: Flickering]

It's more or less like this but only when the redrawing happens:

[image]

Also, if I put a button with border off on it, when clicked the color went off, just like the flickering:

[image]

I tried to set background color in different views/controls, but seems the NSCollectionView will always be black/white (depending on UI color selection) when it's empty:

[image]

Did I missed anything?

**EDIT:**

By adding `scrollView.needsDisplay = false/true` before/after the item change will make some of the flickers gone. Still, most the problems still exist.

Also, if I forcely enabled horizontal scroller bar or disabled autoresize subview, the flicker will no longer show when add/remove items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems disabling the "Autoresize Subviews" on the problematic view will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using a NSTableView inside a NSPopover. I was able to fix it by setting all the controls to the appearance type Aqua instead of dark/light.

Comment: They were set as Aqua (Inherited) and yes it will fix this issue but will no longer change color as I wished to make it's color match the statusbar.